# Check whether car exceeded speed limit between some waypoints GPX

Tags: gratis, graphs, maps, data-analysis

I need a free software to check whether racing car exceeded speed limit between some waypoints.

There are two .gpx files - one has waypoints and another has car track with speeds. I need [something like this](http://www.mygpsfiles.com/app/). This webpage is OK for checking speeds but I cannot upload waypoints along with track and see them both.

Moreover, there would be also great if there would be ability to see the information as a graph - X axis as a speed and Y axis 
as a distance and to see waypoints at a top.

Currently, I am using Google Earth as it has possibility to open both files, but it is slow and uncomfortable and in graph it shows only speed and distance.

Comment: Should it check against speed limits of the particular roads taken? (using a kind of database of speed limits)

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul - there is no database. For example, there is 70 km/h speed limit before village area, then there is two waypoints - one in a beginning of a vilage and second at the end. Speed limit between these waypoints is 50 km/h, so referee must check if speed limit was not exceeded.

Comment: Answers might use OpenStreetMap which has information about speed limits.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul - well, there is a racing competition, so the speeds may vary depending if the roads are closed in some location or there is a public road. OpenStreetMap looks like a nice thing, unfortunately, it is not what I need...

Comment: Do you want the speed to be checked by software, or by human referees looking at segments on a computer screen?

Comment: Checking the speeds by a human referee would be enough. Principally, the main goal is to find software which would give an ability for referee to check the track as fast as possible without making mistakes. However, if you know software which would do that without human interaction, that would be amazing